# In ActionScript 3, is conditional if/else compilation of class variables valid?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air

I'm working with an AS3 class in Flash Builder 4.6, AIR 3.5.

Can anyone confirm that the following if/else syntax is valid in the class definition. I've tested it and it compiles and runs on Mac, but I can't find documentation that supports it.

```
package controller
{
    import flash.desktop.NativeApplication;
    import flash.display.NativeMenu;
    import flash.display.NativeMenuItem;
    import flash.display.NativeWindow;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.EventDispatcher;
    import flash.events.IEventDispatcher;

    [Bindable]
    public class AppMenu extends EventDispatcher
    {
        if (Capabilities.os.search("Mac")>-1) {
            public var titularMenu:NativeMenu;
            public var fileMenu:NativeMenu;
            public var editMenu:NativeMenu;
            private var optionsMenu:NativeMenu;
            private var addOnsMenu:NativeMenu;
            private var helpMenu:NativeMenu;
        } else {
            // Assign same variables as NativeMenuItem, for Windows.
        }

        // etcetera
    }
```

Comment: you can do it with compiler variables eg:  if(CONFIG::Var){

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't have if/else conditionals outside methods or initializers.

For your purpose, you could juste use define the generic properties/methods inside an interface `IAppMenu`, and then have one implementation per OS (of course, you will still need to define which one to create using `Capabilities.os`).

Comment: Thanks for the answer--I suspected that to be the case. However, how would an interface help, because you cannot define variables in interfaces.

Comment: You would be implementing an interface (public class AppMenu implements IAppMenu). You would then have to have all functions as defined in the interface. It would be in the body of those functions you would have to "platform-sniff" (if (Capabilities.os.search("iOS") > -1)...

Comment: @user1834364 You can indeed define getter/setters in interfaces (`function get property():String`). However in your case, I would try to define the contract in another way (because in one case you need to have `NativeMenu` and the other `NativeMenuItem`). The key here is to design by contract - what exactly does an implementation of `IAppMenu` needs to ? Maybe just received initialization data and dispatch some events when the user interacts with menu items.

Comment: And by one implementation by OS, I really meant having `WindowsAppMenu implements IAppMenu` and `MacOSAppMenu implements IAppMenu`.